# Cannot read property 'session' of undefined - Manage Session Cookie Firebase Auth generated cookie

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, session, cookies

The problem that I am facing is that after setting a Firebase session cookie, I go to another endpoint that needs to be secure, but `req` cannot find the cookie.

I am following a Firebase tutorial called [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) that describes how to generate a cookie after a user has logged in using the `Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword` function. The user `idToken` is `then` passed over to a `POST` request:

First, I am generating a token and sending it to an endpoint:

```
function signIn() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('Wrong password.');
    } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
    }

    document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;

  }).then(user => {
    // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
    return user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/login',
          data: {'email':firebase.auth().currentUser.email,idToken},
          success: function(data) {
            //do other things...
          }
        });          
      }      
    });
  })
}
```

The URL endpoint, which is getting the `idToken` from the prior `POST` request, creating a session cookie with `createSessionCookie`, then setting the cookie using `res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options)`:

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {

  // Get the ID token passed
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();

  // Set session expiration to 14 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 * 1000;

  var exampleDB = admin.database().ref('exampleDB');
  exampleDB.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    //unrelated things happening...
    //generate randomData...
  }).then(function() {
    admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})
      .then((sessionCookie) => {
       // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
       const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
       res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
       res.status(200).send(randomData).end();
      }, error => {
       res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');
      });    
  });
};
```

The problem that I am facing starts here, when I go to another endpoint, `/dashboard`. The cookie that I had supposedly set cannot be found, and instead I get an error message stating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined` for my session cookie:

```
exports.dashboard = (req, res, next) => {
  const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
  // a bunch of other code around the session cookie that doesn't even get triggered because of the break in req.cookies.session
}
```

Am I retrieving the cookie incorrectly? Or have I not set the cookie properly? Or is the cookie somehow not being carried over to this new endpoint, `/dashboard`, from the page on which the `POST` to `/login` happens?

After logging the `req` to `/dashboard` I see that I have the following in there, but I don't know if it's from another session for something. If it is from Firebase, I don't know how to access it correctly:

```
  sessionID: 'ublahxARQVljyGRblahPQrei',
  session: 
   Session {
     cookie: 
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true },
     returnTo: '/dashboard',
     flash: {},
     _csrfSecret: 'r46blahE+kOzblah5==' },
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to use the `__session` cookie.

> When using Firebase Hosting together with Cloud Functions or Cloud
>   Run, cookies are generally stripped from incoming requests.
>   [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies)

This has been encountered before in a different form: [Firebase Functions : How to store simple cookies to remember an authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728312/firebase-functions-how-to-store-simple-cookies-to-remember-an-authenticated-us/49986813#49986813)

Comment: and there is great example in official firebase functions samples page on github, with cors usage also - https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js